# Single tt_content column for content element with many fields in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm currently working on a custom content element with custom fields in Typo3 (Version 8.7).

My question is if it's possible (and/or reasonable) to create a content element with a list of custom fields based on a **single** column in the *tt_content* table containing all the data in form of a serialized array?

I thought about this as an alternative for extending tt_content with a lot of columns. I already tried it with the pre- and postprocessFieldArray hooks, but I didn't yet find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

This concept already is used from some extensions to define new CEs (TemplaVoila, gridelements, fluidcontent, dce, ...). So they do not use serialized data but XML.

Even the core does use it since ever:
for plugins (field `Ctype` = 'list') there is an option to store configuration in the field `pi_flexform`.

depending on the kind of extension the handling does differ a little bit. you can find code examples on [this page](http://pi-phi.de/171.html) (german).
Look at the XML definition files which use a syntax similar to TCA and which enable the core to build proper forms to fill.

---

and now: **why you should not do it:**

Flexforms have some drawbacks which will catch you in some time.

1. handling of wrapping/unwrapping is more complex than accessing fields directly.
2. you have no possibility to do simple queries as a value is inside an XML in a text field.
3. changes to the structure require complicated update processes and mostly changes to your code.

I don't think that serialized data, JSon or similar in a text field can be handled much better. Serialized may be worse, as a simple edit, which can be done in XML easily, might invalidate your data.

Each such attempt of compressed data waste the space of the fields already existing and which you will not free: have a look how many fields are available in the tt_content records.

---

If you want a good extension for your own CEs (Content Elements) you may evaluate `EXT:mask` (as a kickstarter) and `EXT:mask_export` which enables you to recycle all these fields for your own purpose and generate new simple fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I think I'll have a closer look at mask.